# Server returns invalid user when sending login details via POST

Tags: android, json, post, httpurlconnection

Hi im currently trying to get working an image upload on Android, im trying to upload an image and parse some json data that is returned. When ever i try to pass the data in i either get a 500 error or json saying that it is an invalid user. I cant get to the Server side code as that is on the clinets end and they will not release that to me or give me access. Im slowly going insane as everything ive looked at says this should work, for my own sanity is there anything ive missed or done wrong here am i passing the login details incorrectly or what? A fresh pair of eyes would be extremely appreciated here thanks.

```
 class PostImage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Log.i("Api Handler", "Beginning Image upload.");

        String crlf = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";

        try {

            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            //Compress image into Jpeg format to make the file small enough.
            image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, bos);
            byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();

            String charset = "UTF-8";

            //Open Http Connection
            URL url = new URL(Utilities.uploadImageApi);
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.addRequestProperty(URLEncoder.encode("username", charset), URLEncoder.encode("username", charset));
            conn.addRequestProperty(URLEncoder.encode("password", charset), URLEncoder.encode("password", charset));
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "image/jpeg");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setDoInput(true);
            conn.setDoOutput(true);

            //conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Disposition", "form-statsDataArray; name=name; filename=" + fileName +".jpg");

            DataOutputStream dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + crlf);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition; form-statsDataArray; name=name" + "; filename=" + fileName + ".jpeg");
            dos.writeBytes(crlf);
            dos.write(data);
            dos.writeBytes(crlf);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + crlf);
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

            if(conn.getResponseCode() == 200) {
                InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getInputStream());
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;

                try {

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    try {
                        in.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Log.i("Api Handler", sb.toString());

            } else {
                Log.i("Api Handler", "Bad Response from Image Upload " + conn.getResponseCode() +
                        " Message: " + conn.getResponseMessage());
                //Log.e("Api Handler", conn.getErrorStream().toString());
                InputStream i = new BufferedInputStream(conn.getErrorStream());
                //Get Error specifics
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i));
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                String line;

                try {

                    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(line + "\n");
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } finally {

                    try {
                        i.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                Log.i("Api Handler", sb.toString());


            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.i("Api Handler", "Upload Failed");
            Log.e("Api Handler", "" + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

For Obvious reasons ive changed the login details being passed in to generic username and password these will become variables passed in at a later date once ive got it working with the test account.

Comment: It is a lot of code to quickly read over.  Can you point out the main problem areas?

Comment: I believe the problem area is when im opening a HttpURLConnection im pretty sure im passing the login details correctly but it either returns a 500 error or some JSON saying its an invalid user. now i know its reaching the server when it returns the JSON i just want to know if im forming the request correctly at this moment in time ive never uploaded an image before to a server via Android.